# CQWP Renders only in Edit Mode

Tags: sharepoint, cqwp

I have customized CQWP (Content Query Web Part) to display items from my sub sites.  The items are filtered based on my custom content type.

I have cusomized the rendering of additional fields in CQWP using ItemStyle.xsl.

I am having a strange issue that my web part is able to render data when the page is in Edit mode,  however when i exit the edit mode, the web part is not showing any data.

Any Help, Pointers,
Sudhir Kesharwani

Answer (score 6):

I have figured out the issue,  the CQWP has a property called "UseCache".  By default this property is set to "True",  this conflicts with the web part rendering.

To resolve this,  I exported my web part onto my local machine and updated the "UseCache" property to "False"

```
<property name="UseCache" type="bool">False</property>
```

This worked like charm. My sincere thatnks to [Michael Nemtsev](http://msmvps.com/blogs/laflour/archive/2008/12/24/why-content-query-web-part-cqwp-doesn-t-return-all-results.aspx)

Regards,
Sudhir Kesharwani

Comment: Fantastic start from a new StackOverflow users - Good question and you came back to it with a clear answer and a reference. Wish all new StackOverflow users were as conscientious + 2 internets from me!